# Algebraic Number Theory and Euler's constant

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, advice

After studying Herstein's books for Algebra (undergraduate and graduate) alongside some books in Analytic Number Theory, I decided to study Algebraic Number Theory as well. I read a recommendation on MSE (I don't remember the link) for [Alaca's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521540119) wonderful book and I just finished it!

My research interest is on Euler's constant and I was wondering do I have study more advanced book(s) on *Algebraic* Number Theory?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Your interest in the Euler-*Mascheroni* constant is driven by the fact that you might want to prove its irrationality? In such a case I would rather suggest a crash course in Diophantine Approximation and Beuker integrals.

Comment: But I would also suggest you to stay away from long-standing open problems. They might be rewarding, but they might be extremely disappointing, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Thank you for your comment. When I first saw Euler-Mascheroni constant was in Advanced Calculus and my hope that I might be able to prove its irrationality lead me to learn many areas of mathematics and also increased my interest in abstract algebra which I didn't like it beforehand. In short, it has many good 'side-effects'! :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I have studied the two vols *Analytic Number Theory* by Apostol, Hardy's  number theory, *Gamma* by Havil, *Making Transcendence Transparent* by Burger, *Algebraic Number Theory* by Alaca and introductory texts in continued fractions. I can read some of the papers written on EMC but should I learn more subjects in math to have broader knowledge and better tools? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a purely book recommendation question, or is there a math question about the Euler constant as well?

Comment: @D.R., I want to learn advanced Algebraic Number Theory oriented to help with research on Euler's constant, i.e. if undergrad book Algebraic Number Theory is enough so I won't study a more advanced one. PS - I wanted to post a similar question, to avoid duplicate question I set the bounty on this, instead. Note that the OP is "dead" so please add L.G. for I'd be noticed. Thanks! :)